# delete rows based on criteria in multiple sheets

Tags: excel, vba

I used this code to look for the words written in in Cell (10,2) in different rows of table in multiple Sheets in the same workbook, and when found the word, the code will delete the entire row in each table, the issue is that the code is applied in the first sheet where the command button is on and not applied on other sheets, so please your help in this.

```
sub Deletrows_Click()

Dim WS As Worksheet
Dim pattern As String

For Each WS In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    With WS
        pattern = Cells(10, 2) ' delete row if found the word total in it
        RowCount = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count

        Dim i As Integer
        For i = 2 To RowCount
            Dim j As Integer
            For j = 1 To 3 'find the word within this range
                If Cells(i, j) = pattern Then
                    Cells(i, j).EntireRow.Delete 
                End If
            Next j
        Next i
    End With
Next WS

End Sub
```

Comment: Many Thanks Shai for your kind assistance, it helps a lot

Answer (score 2):

You need to fully qualify all your `Range` and `Cells` inside the `With WS` statement, by adding the `.` as a prefix.

E.g. instead of `pattern = Cells(10, 2)` use `pattern = .Cells(10, 2)` , the `.Cells(10, 2)` means Cells(10, 2) of `WS` , which is being advanced in your `For Each WS In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets`.

**Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub Deletrows_Click()

Dim WS As Worksheet
Dim pattern As String
Dim RowCount As Long, i As Long, j As Long

For Each WS In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    With WS
        pattern = .Cells(10, 2) ' delete row if found the word total in it
        RowCount = .UsedRange.Rows.Count

        For i = 2 To RowCount
            For j = 1 To 3 'find the word within this range
                If .Cells(i, j) = pattern Then
                    .Cells(i, j).EntireRow.Delete
                End If
            Next j
        Next i
    End With
Next WS

End Sub
```

---

**Option 2**: Instead of using two `For` loops, you could replace the 2nd `For` loop with the `Application.Match` function, to look for a certain value throughout the row.

**Code with Match**

```
Option Explicit

Sub Deletrows_Click()

Dim WS As Worksheet
Dim pattern As String
Dim RowCount As Long, i As Long, j As Long

For Each WS In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    With WS
        pattern = .Cells(10, 2) ' delete row if found the word total in it
        RowCount = .UsedRange.Rows.Count

        For i = 2 To RowCount
            ' use the Match function to find the word inside a certain row
            If Not IsError(Application.Match(pattern, .Range(.Cells(i, 1), .Cells(i, 3)), 0)) Then '<-- match was successful
                .Cells(i, 1).EntireRow.Delete
            End If                            
        Next i
    End With
Next WS

End Sub
```

---

**Edit 2**:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Deletrows_Click()

Dim WS As Worksheet
Dim pattern As String
Dim FirstRow As Long, RowCount As Long, i As Long, j As Long
Dim FirstCol, ColCount As Long

For Each WS In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    With WS
        pattern = .Cells(10, 2) ' delete row if found the word total in it
        FirstRow = .UsedRange.Row
        RowCount = .UsedRange.Rows.Count
        FirstCol = .UsedRange.Column
        ColCount = .UsedRange.Columns.Count

        For i = 2 To RowCount + FirstRow
            ' use the Match function to find the word inside a certain row
            If Not IsError(Application.Match(pattern, .Range(.Cells(i, 1), .Cells(i, ColCount + FirstCol)), 0)) Then '<-- match was successful
                .Cells(i, 1).EntireRow.Delete
            End If
        Next i
    End With
Next WS

End Sub
```

Comment: firstly, thanks for your kind assistance. I tried the second code it works well but it deleted the matched words in Cells(10,2) in all sheets only and ignored any other similar words in other columns or rows. to express myself better. say I want to delete any row in any sheets that has the word Red Apple. so would you please assist?

Comment: @NabilAmer you want to remove the word found in `Cells(10,2)` from the entire sheet ? cause your post you are looking at columns A to C only

Comment: Hi Shai, I tried the Edit 2 it works only if the Cells (10,2) have the required word but if not found it will not work on other sheets. the cells(10,2) is in sheet1 which needs to be exclude, so I added the following code and it works as needed (pattern = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(10, 2) and also this (If WS.Name <> "Sheet1" Then). now it works well. I have one more question if it could be, how can I use Input box without asking me to repeat the entry of the required data as I used this code also pattern = InputBox("Please enter the selected ID.")

Comment: @NabilAmer not sure I understand, you want to enter the value in the `InputBox` only once ? if that's the case just put this code line before the `For Each WS In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets` line

Comment: Great Many thanks Boss, it works very well. appreciate it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135572/discussion-between-nabil-amer-and-shai-rado).

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub Deletrows_Click()

Dim WS As Worksheet
Dim pattern As String
Dim FirstRow As Long, RowCount As Long, i As Long, j As Long
Dim FirstCol, ColCount As Long

For Each WS In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    With WS
        pattern = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(10, 2) ' delete row if found the word in this source sheet
        FirstRow = .UsedRange.Row
        RowCount = .UsedRange.Rows.Count
        FirstCol = .UsedRange.Column
        ColCount = .UsedRange.Columns.Count

        For i = 2 To RowCount + FirstRow
            ' use the Match function to find the word inside a certain row
            If WS.Name <> "Sheet1" Then 'I added this to exclude the said sheet as a source page
            If Not IsError(Application.Match(pattern, .Range(.Cells(i, 1), .Cells(i, ColCount + FirstCol)), 0)) Then '<-- match was successful
            .Cells(i, 1).EntireRow.Delete
            End If
            End If
        Next i
    End With
Next WS

End Sub
```